# Loop integral using Feynman's trick

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration

I am trying to show for the one-loop integral with three propagators with different internal masses $m_1$, $m_2$, $m_3$, and all off-shell external momenta $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$ the following formula appearing in 't Hooft(1979), Bardin (1999), Denner (2007):  (unfortunate metric $-,+,+,+$)

$$\int d^d q\frac{1}{(q^2+m_1^2)((q+p1)^2+m_2^2)((q+p_1+p_2)^2+m_3^2)}
$$
$$=i\pi^2\int_0^1dx\int_0^xdy\frac{1}{ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+f}$$

where $a$, $b$, $c$, ... are coefficients depending on the momenta in the following way:

$a=-p_2^2$,

$b=-p_1^2$,

$c=-2p_1.p_2$,

$d=m_2^2-m_3^2+p_2^2$,

$e=m_1^2-m_2^2+p_1^2+2(p_1.p_2)$,

$f=m_3^2-i\epsilon$.

I don't really care about factors in fromt like $i\pi^2$.  My **simple problem** is:  I am totally unable to reproduce coefficients $d$, $e$ and $f$.  The problem is, when I integrate over the third Feynman parameter, $m_3$ appears in all three coefficients $d$, $e$ and $f$.  How do I squeeze the denominators to reproduce this formula?

Comment: I am a little confused - you are indicating you are having trouble with a 3rd Feynman parameter, when the identity you wrote only has 2?

Comment: Ah yes.  When I attempted to derive the identity, I had a third parameter $z$ accompanied by the delta function $\delta(1-x-y-z)$.  After integrating over $z$ (which I thought would be trivial), I got *something* like the identity in my post, but the coefficients came out wrong.  I need help with the coefficients.

Comment: I think the limits on the remaining 2 Feynman parameter integrals should instead be: $\int_0^1 dx \int_0^{1-x} dy $.

Comment: Isn't $q$ the variable you should be integrating over in your first formula?

Comment: @DJBunk Good observation!  I totally missed that, and in fact 't Hooft made a change of variables in the $x$ integration: $x\rightarrow 1-x$ to arrive at his formula.  I now am able to get the correct coefficients.  Many thanks!

Comment: @Learningisamess Yes, thanks for catching that typo.  It is now fixed.

Comment: Maybe you should post your answer for future users? It's received 5 upvotes so there seems to be interest in it.

Comment: I will echo what DJBunk said, it would be great if you post an answer to show how you were able to solve the problem, so anyone stumbling across this page in the future can benefit from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the LHS of the equation above:

$$I=\int d^d q\frac{1}{(q^2+m_1^2)((q+p_1)^2+m_2^2)((q+p_1+p_2)^2+m_3^2)}$$

The first step is to squeeze the denominators using Feynman's trick:

$$I=\int_0^1 dx\,dy\,dz\,\delta(1-x-y-z)\int d^d q\frac{2}{[y(q^2+m_1^2)+z((q+p_1)^2+m_2^2)+x((q+p_1+p_2)^2+m_3^2)]^3}$$

The square in $q^2$ may be completed in the denominator by expanding:

$$[\text{denom}]=q^2+2q.(z p_1+x(p_1+p_2))+y m_1^2+z (p_1^2+m_2^2)+x(m_3^2+(p_1+p_2)^2)$$
$$=q^2+2q.Q+A^2\,$$

where $Q^\mu=z p_1^\mu+x(p_1+p_2)^\mu$ and $A^2=y m_1^2+z (p_1^2+m_2^2)+x(m_3^2+(p_1+p_2)^2)$, and by shifting the momentum, $q^\mu=(k-Q)^\mu$ as a change of integration variables.  Upon performing the $k$ integral, we are left with integrals over Feynman parameters (because this integral has three propagators, it is UV finite):

$$I=i\pi^2\int_0^1 dx\,dy\,dz\,\delta(1-x-y-z)\frac{1}{[-Q^2+A^2]}$$

Now integrate over $z$ with the help of the Dirac delta:

$$I=i\pi^2\int_0^1 dx\int_0^{1-x}dy \frac{1}{[-Q^2+A^2]_{z\rightarrow1-y-z}}$$

To arrive at the RHS of the OP's equation(**which is the part I forgot to do**), we make a final change of variables: $x=1-x'$:

So that the denominator reads $ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+f$, with the coefficients $a,b,c,\ldots$ exactly defined in the question of OP.  Note the change in the range of integration in $y$.

$$I=i\pi^2\int_0^1dx\int_0^xdy\frac{1}{ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+f}$$