# Feynman Parameterization for the three-propagator problem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dimensional-regularization

I am considering the three particle scattering problem, where I have the loop integral

$$ \int \frac{d^dp}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{1}{((p_1-k)^2-m^2+i\varepsilon)((p_3+k)^2-m^2+i\varepsilon)(k^2-m^2+i\varepsilon)}. $$

In the paper "Scalar one-loop integrals" by G. 't Hooft and M. Veltman (Nuclear Physics B153 (1979)), they rewrite this integral using (what I assume is) dimensional regularization techniques, to obtain

$$ \int_0^1 dx\int_0^x dy [ax^2 + by^2 + cxy+dx+ey+f]^{-1}$$
where $a, b,\dots$ are constants depending on the masses and momenta of the particles (page 372). I have learned a bit about Feynman Parameterization and in my calculations I have found the above integral to be

$$\int_0^1dx \int_0^1dy \ln(m^2-x(1-x)p_2^2 -y(1-y)p_1^2 -2xyp_1\cdot p_2).$$

I don't know how to obtain the result in the paper. I haven't seen any Feynman parameterization derivations which include integral limits that aren't $0$ and $1$, and I haven't been able to figure it out myself. Is there something I've missed or misunderstood?

[Here is a link to the 't Hooft & Veltman paper.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321379906059?via%3Dihub)

In the paper they say "consider the integral

$$ \int_0^1 dx \int_0^xdy \frac{1}{[ax^2+by^2+cxy\dots]}.$$

This is just another version of the Feynman parameters." (Page 369) But as before, it's a mystery to me how they obtained this. Where should I begin in trying to derive this?

Comment: Feynman parametric integration is of the form $\int_0^{\color{red}1}\mathrm dx\int_0^{\color{red}x}\mathrm dy\int_0^{\color{red}y}\mathrm dz\cdots$, cf. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization).

Comment: This is the part I'm struggling with - the derivations don't explicitly state this, and I'm struggling to make the logical leap myself.

Comment: Using Feynman parameters conventionally with the constraining delta gives $\int_0^1 \text{d}x \int_0^{1-x} \text{d}z$. If you let $z=1-y$, you recover the expression given except that the lower border of $y$ is 1 and not 0.

Comment: I think you forgot the Delta function in the beginning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop integral using Feynman's trick](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54992/loop-integral-using-feynmans-trick)